# Why am I not getting a response when I try to pass POST vars via script?

Tags: php, autohotkey

I set up a test webpage that I am trying to pass information to (in order to cause an action), but when I try it, nothing happens. When I run this in a web browser I get the output from the else condition then the word DONE like I expected. Why is my AHK script not returning data from the if condition?

**test.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['userMe'].$_POST['passME'];
if(isset($_POST['userMe']))
{
    echo "user value was passed by POST var when page was loaded. Do action.....this is what I expect to happen";
}   
else
{
    echo "no user provided by POST var";
}   
echo '<br>DONE';
?>
```

**web_request.ahk**

```
#include httpQuery.ahk
#noenv
#SingleInstance force
html     := ""
URL      := "http://MY_IP_HERE/test.php"
POSTData := "userME=hello&passME=bye"

length := httpQuery(html,URL,POSTdata)
varSetCapacity(html,-1)

Gui,Add,Edit,w600 +Wrap r25,% html
Gui,Show
Return

GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
   ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with the `httpQuery.ahk` function, perhaps you should ask the author there if you're using it properly. I've never used it before.

I use a similar function to accomplish this, called `InternetFileRead`, and it works for me. Perhaps you can try that. Unfortunately it was written by [SKAN on the old AHK forums](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic45718.html) who is known for his poorly formatted code in his misguided attempt to write code as compactly as possible. See the link for the func parameter descriptions.

Here's what your example would look something like:

```
response := ""
url := "http://MY_IP_HERE/test.php?userME=hello&passME=bye"
size_to_read := 1024
dl_buffer := 128

length := InternetFileRead(response, url, size_to_read, dl_buffer)

Gui,Add,Edit,w600 +Wrap r25,% html
Gui,Show
return


; http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic45718.html
InternetFileRead( ByRef V, URL="", RB=0, bSz=1024, DLP="DLP", F=0x84000000 ) {
 Static LIB="WININET\", CL="00000000000000", N=""
 QRL := 16
 If ! DllCall( "GetModuleHandle", Str,"wininet.dll" )
      DllCall( "LoadLibrary", Str,"wininet.dll" )
 If ! hIO:=DllCall( LIB "InternetOpenA", Str,N, UInt,4, Str,N, Str,N, UInt,0 )
   Return -1
 If ! (( hIU:=DllCall( LIB "InternetOpenUrlA", UInt,hIO, Str,URL, Str,N, Int,0, UInt,F
                                                            , UInt,0 ) ) || ErrorLevel )
   Return 0 - ( !DllCall( LIB "InternetCloseHandle", UInt,hIO ) ) - 2
 If ! ( RB  )
 If ( SubStr(URL,1,4) = "ftp:" )
    CL := DllCall( LIB "FtpGetFileSize", UInt,hIU, UIntP,0 )
 Else If ! DllCall( LIB "HttpQueryInfoA", UInt,hIU, Int,5, Str,CL, UIntP,QRL, UInt,0 )
   Return 0 - ( !DllCall( LIB "InternetCloseHandle", UInt,hIU ) )
            - ( !DllCall( LIB "InternetCloseHandle", UInt,hIO ) ) - 4
 VarSetCapacity( V,64 ), VarSetCapacity( V,0 )
 SplitPath, URL, FN,,,, DN
 FN:=(FN ? FN : DN), CL:=(RB ? RB : CL), VarSetCapacity( V,CL,32 ), P:=&V,
 B:=(bSz>CL ? CL : bSz), TtlB:=0, LP := RB ? "Unknown" : CL,  %DLP%( True,CL,FN )
 Loop {
       If ( DllCall( LIB "InternetReadFile", UInt,hIU, UInt,P, UInt,B, UIntP,R ) && !R )
       Break
       P:=(P+R), TtlB:=(TtlB+R), RemB:=(CL-TtlB), B:=(RemB<B ? RemB : B), %DLP%( TtlB,LP )
       Sleep -1
 } TtlB<>CL ? VarSetCapacity( T,TtlB ) DllCall( "RtlMoveMemory", Str,T, Str,V, UInt,TtlB )
  . VarSetCapacity( V,0 ) . VarSetCapacity( V,TtlB,32 ) . DllCall( "RtlMoveMemory", Str,V
  , Str,T, UInt,TtlB ) . %DLP%( TtlB, TtlB ) : N
 If ( !DllCall( LIB "InternetCloseHandle", UInt,hIU ) )
  + ( !DllCall( LIB "InternetCloseHandle", UInt,hIO ) )
   Return -6
Return, VarSetCapacity(V)+((ErrorLevel:=(RB>0 && TtlB<RB)||(RB=0 && TtlB=CL) ? 0 : 1)<<64)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Unfortunately that still didnt work for me. I will try the AHK forums and report back if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

httpquery works only some of the time. My advice, use the built in WinHttpRequest object. Need latest version of AHK. Plus it looks like you're wanting to pass URL parameters and not post data.

```
param := "hello"
msgbox, % url_tovar("http://fischgeek.com/playground/dbfree-test/?q=" param)

url_tovar(URL) { 
    WebRequest := ComObjCreate("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    WebRequest.Open("GET", URL)
    WebRequest.Send()
    res := WebRequest.ResponseText
    return res
}
```

This can handle post data too. I'll have to find some time to provide an example if you're interested.

Comment: I would love to see an example using POST data if you have time. Your GET example worked perfectly for me but when I tried to adapt it for POST I failed somehow :)

Comment: Well, theoretically, you would just change it from GET to POST and pass your data to Send(). I'll see if I can find time today to get a working example.